# How to disable button so user can't enable it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple button (for example with ID: `new-product`).
When I click on it it add **partial view** to the specified `div` on page.
Is it possible to set disable on `new-product` button so that user can't click on it again.
But also to prevent that user change something in browser and set it to enabled `true` again?

Comment: Yes, remove the button and replace it with an image. though, nothing is stopping them from putting the button back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
$('#new-product').attr('disabled','disabled')
```

to enable

```
$('#new-product').removeAttr('disabled');
```

or you can set attr to ""

```
$('#new-product').attr('disabled', '');
```

Comment: But this still allow user to change disable option on button? I wonder how linkedin did this when editing profile.

Comment: Like @Ali said, ultimately web client can manipulate anything on the page and indeed in the request or submitted data.  You should validate form and apply business logic on the server side. Disabling the button / replacing it / hiding it is only really there to improve user experience

Answer (score 2):

You can set the disabled attribute on a button as sambormartin suggests, but a user can **always** change the HTML, CSS, and javascript from their browser. You cannot rely on client side validation. You must validate all inputs on the server side.